# Как сохранить значения из localStorage в select-option что бы после перезагрузки страницы они оставались в select-option?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
  function loadSelectValue(el) {
  let valueFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("newUserExercise");

  if (valueFromLocalStorage) {
    let parseValue = JSON.parse(valueFromLocalStorage);

      let select = document.getElementById("exercise");
      for(index in parseValue){
        let userOptions = new Option(parseValue)
        select.append(userOptions);
        select.value = parseValue.exercise;
        console.log(select);
    }
 
    console.log(parseValue);
  }
}
loadSelectValue();
```

Comment: Localstorage не для этого у вас используется?

Comment: В localStiorage хранится значение из select, мне нужно что бы эти значения сохранялись в selec как новые options после перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема? У вас в `localStorage` не сохраняются данные? Или при парсинге проблемы? Или `option` не можете создать? Или не получается `option` в `select` запихнуть? Или `select` не реагирует на новые значения?

Comment: не могу option создать, Вот вы как пользователь,  добавили новое значение в выпадающем списке, обновили страницу и оно там осталось (ваше значение). Мне нужно достать из хранилища (сделал), и сохранить в выпадающем списке (не получается)

Comment: Потому что вы неправильно его создаёте. Ознакомьтесь с [документацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option), пожалуйста